# How do I conduct stress tests on a microservice using Debezium that doesn't expose APIs?

Tags: spring, debezium, cdc

I have always used tools like Taurus or JMeter to conduct stress tests on APIs, simulating parallel calls and high-load situations.

However, I am now working on an application that uses Debezium and is designed to be always up and running, without exposing any APIs.

In this scenario, how can I perform effective stress tests?

Additional information: I am using the Spring Framework, and in addition to processing data row by row, there's also transcoding and various business logic involved. Ideally, I would like to understand how to subject the environment to stress tests.

Answer (score 1):

writing this as an answer as the comment becomes truncated.

End to end tests & load tests : E2E tests will entail you to load database tables with load operations. The time for propagation of a change will depend on debezium config (how often to poll for changes), how long does the CDC propagation happens in the database table etc.

In a typical environment you want the stress test right from the time a delta is created from the table (change bin files, CDC tables in SQL Server etc) and how these will get propagated to Kafka. So typically from a spring boot application, the stress test may entail you to perform bulk operation on the table (x C/U/D operations) then looking at the the time it takes for the enqueue to happen.

If you have consumers that are reading off the topic, you can also look at lag for example (true E2E scenario that includes consumers as well)

To load the database, again you can use JMeter, Gatling or a similar tooling (tooling should not matter)